# Getting "nan" with cross_val_score and StackingClassifier or Voting Classifier

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, supervised-learning, ensemble-learning

I want to use StackingClassifier & VotingClassifier with StratifiedKFold & cross_val_score. I am getting nan values in cross_val_score if I use StackingClassifier or VotingClassifier. If I use any other algorithm instead of StackingClassifier or VotingClassifier,cross_val_score works fine.
I am using python 3.8.5 & sklearn 0.23.2.

Updating code to working example. Please use this Parkinons dataset from kaggle [Parkinsons Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/nidaguler/parkinsons-data-set) This is the dataset I have been working on and below are the exact steps I have followed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn import feature_selection

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

dataset = pd.read_csv('parkinsons.csv')


FS_X=dataset.iloc[:,:-1]
FS_y=dataset.iloc[:,-1:]

FS_X.drop(['name'],axis=1,inplace=True)

select_k_best = feature_selection.SelectKBest(score_func=feature_selection.f_classif,k=15)
X_k_best = select_k_best.fit_transform(FS_X,FS_y)

supportList = select_k_best.get_support().tolist()
p_valuesList = select_k_best.pvalues_.tolist()

toDrop=[]

for i in np.arange(len(FS_X.columns)):
    bool = supportList[i]
    if(bool == False):
        toDrop.append(FS_X.columns[i])     

FS_X.drop(toDrop,axis=1,inplace=True)        

smote = SMOTE(random_state=7)
Balanced_X,Balanced_y = smote.fit_sample(FS_X,FS_y)
before = pd.merge(FS_X,FS_y,right_index=True, left_index=True)
after = pd.merge(Balanced_X,Balanced_y,right_index=True, left_index=True)
b=before['status'].value_counts()
a=after['status'].value_counts()
print('Before')
print(b)
print('After')
print(a)

SkFold = model_selection.StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7, shuffle=False)

estimators_list = list()

KNN = KNeighborsClassifier()
RF = RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy',random_state = 1)
DT = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy',random_state = 1)
GNB = GaussianNB()
LR = LogisticRegression(random_state = 1)

estimators_list.append(LR)
estimators_list.append(RF)
estimators_list.append(DT)
estimators_list.append(GNB)

SCLF = StackingClassifier(estimators = estimators_list,final_estimator = KNN,stack_method = 'predict_proba',cv=SkFold,n_jobs = -1)
VCLF = VotingClassifier(estimators = estimators_list,voting = 'soft',n_jobs = -1)

scores1 = model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator = SCLF,X=Balanced_X.values,y=Balanced_y.values,scoring='accuracy',cv=SkFold)
print('StackingClassifier Scores',scores1)

scores2 = model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator = VCLF,X=Balanced_X.values,y=Balanced_y.values,scoring='accuracy',cv=SkFold)
print('VotingClassifier Scores',scores2)

scores3 = model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator = DT,X=Balanced_X.values,y=Balanced_y.values,scoring='accuracy',cv=SkFold)
print('DecisionTreeClassifier Scores',scores3)
```

**Output**

```
Before
1    147
0     48
Name: status, dtype: int64
After
1    147
0    147
Name: status, dtype: int64
StackingClassifier Scores [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
VotingClassifier Scores [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
DecisionTreeClassifier Scores [0.86666667 0.9        0.93333333 0.86666667 0.96551724 0.82758621
 0.75862069 0.86206897 0.86206897 0.93103448]
```

I checked some other related posts on Stackoverflow but couldn't solve my issue. I am not able to understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you make a minimal working example? Check [this Stackoverflow help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for information. Regarding a dataset, there are a lot of open datasets available also in `sklearn`, which you can use to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @flyingdutchman Updated for minimal working example.

Comment: If I download your example data I get a file `parkinsons.data`, which I rename to `parkinsons.csv`. Then I run your code and get the following error:
`ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'`. That error is caused by line:`File "code.py", line 47 Balanced_X,Balanced_y = smote.fit_sample(FS_X,FS_y)`
How did you get your output? Did you modify the parkinsons data maybe beforehand?

I think you can improve your example. It is not yet minimal. Try to have an example where removing one line or variable will have the cause that your problem doesn't happen.

Comment: Apologies. I forgot that  I had moved the status column (which is the target feature) to the right most end in parkinsons.csv. Issue is files cannot be uploaded directly here.  Anyway, I uploaded Parkinsons.csv on my  [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1knRRL247eejKgXqogLUTtj4NPDvK5_jA/view)

Comment: Here is the [Jupyter notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sGwD2cEBt8nAV-qI2bjYvHLXWkFcJ1KN/view)

Comment: @flyingdutchman Now you can just download both of these and run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `estimators_list` as it is passed to `StackingClassifier` or `VotingClassifier` is incorrect. The [documentation on sklearn for StackingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html) says:

> Base estimators which will be stacked together. Each element of the list is defined as a tuple of string (i.e. name) and an estimator instance. An estimator can be set to ‘drop’ using set_params.

So a correct list would look the following:

```
KNN = KNeighborsClassifier()
DT = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy")
GNB = GaussianNB()

estimators_list = [("KNN", KNN), ("DT", DT), ("GNB", GNB)]
```

And a complete minimal working example with your parkinsons data could look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier


dataset = pd.read_csv("parkinsons.csv")

FS_X = dataset.drop(["name", "status"], axis=1)
FS_y = dataset["status"]

estimators_list = [("KNN", KNeighborsClassifier()), ("DT", DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy")), ("GNB", GaussianNB())]

SCLF = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimators_list)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(FS_X, FS_y)
SCLF.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("SCLF: ", accuracy_score(y_test, SCLF.predict(X_test)))
```

Comment: @flyingducthman, thanks for your comment. I got the answer on Scikit-Learn sometime ago.